# How would i create an instance of a object after a user creates their account using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

As of right now i have the user model from the Devise gem, and i have also created a Player model to store information that i need for my app. All I'm trying to do is make a new Player whenever a User creates an account. The Player model has 3 columns - one for the user_id, one for the game_id and one for the deck_id.

```
#schema.rb

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "players"
    t.integer "player_count"
    t.boolean "rogue", default: true
    t.boolean "wizard", default: true
    t.boolean "paladin", default: true
    t.boolean "barbarian", default: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "last_selected_deck"
  end

  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_players_on_company_id"
    t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_players_on_game_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "game_id"], name: "index_players_on_user_id_and_game_id", unique: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_players_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "company_id", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

```
#user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_player

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
  
  has_one :player, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :game, through: :player

  def create_player
    #code
  end

end
```

i thought i could create a method inside the user.rb model that should be executed after creation, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think you should just take a time out here and consider if you have actually modeled this correctly and if what you're trying to do is even a good idea. If you want to allow users to participate in multiple games you want to have a many to many assocation and you would create those rows in the join table when a user joins a game. Not when the user record is created.

Comment: a user can play one game at a time and many games overall, the game_id would be updated in the beginning and in the end of a game, the same goes for the deck_id, but the user_id should always stay the same

Comment: Yeah, you don't want a callback and you need to rethink these assocations. What you're calling "Player" should really be a join table between users and games. If you want to keep track of the "current game" you would add an additional column to the users table that points to that specifically.

Comment: I did add a table with game_id to my user model and that worked, the problem was that whenever i tried joining a game, the user's id wouldn't get appended to the players list

Comment: Yeah, you need both assocations. Take a step away from the code. Get a cup of coffee and a peice of paper and draw up a diagram of your models and how they are connected and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Last question before i sketch it out, do you think there is a need for a "players" table or is it okay if i just modify the devise users table?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with editing the users table and that would keep it simple. If you want to you can separate the concepts of authentication accounts and "user profiles" in the application but it's not strictly neccissary.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the user-player association, so you can do something like this:

```rb
  def create_player
    self.player.create!
    # Player.create!(user_id: self.id) # without taking account assiciation
  end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i tried doing this, but it prompted me with the following error

NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass

why does it even go to the devise registration controller, shouldnt this use the create from the players controller?

Comment: instead of `after_create` try `after_create_commit`